# Use unicode filenames with Module::Starter

Tags: perl, unicode, perl-module

#### Background:

I whish to create a distribution that contains a few modules for personal use — it will never see the light of day (aka. CPAN). I would like to start these modules using `Module::Starter` to leverage easy testing, and version management.

(perl 5.12.4 on Ubuntu GNU/Linux)

#### Question:

How do I use Unicode filenames with Module::Starter, e.g. `Local::Λ` ← (Lambda)?

This doesn't work:

```
$ module-starter --module Local::Λ
Invalid module name: Local::Λ at /usr/local/share/perl/5.12.4/Module/Starter/App.pm line 132.
```

The line that actually fails is

```
croak "Invalid module name: $_" unless /\A[a-z_]\w*(?:::[\w]+)*\Z/i;
```

in [`Module::Starter::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/source/XSAWYERX/Module-Starter-1.60/lib/Module/Starter/Simple.pm) (line 95).

The Lambda clearly is a "word" character.

This works, by the way:

```
$ cat > xΛ.pm
use utf8;
package xΛ;
sub foo { print "42\n" }
1;
^D
$ perl -Mutf8 -MxΛ -e 'xΛ::foo()'
42
$
```

#### Things I have not yet tried:

- spending a day compiling perl 5.16 for more unicode goodness.
- hacking away at the source, and enabling anything remotely connected to unicode.
- Checking that this isn't just a restriction on *distribution names* (which I am not concerned about, as CPAN will never see this).
- Checking if this could be a `Getopt::Long` problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of 'word character' changes with: a) your version of perl. b) If the script in question is using your input as a binary string or a character string. Check out the `/a` & `/u`  flags of recent versions of perl's regex engine.

FYI:  Because the Perl folks strive for cross-platform compatibility and there is widely varying support for Unicode in various filesystems, they've decided not to support Unicode Module Names at this time.

---

Resolution from Amon's Comment:
this did the trick:

```
perl -Mutf8 -M5.012 -MModule::Starter::App -E'$ARGV[1]="Local::\x{039B}";Module::Starter::App->run' -- --module Local::Λ --license gpl3 --ignore git
```

(Using `\x{...}` escapes forces unicode, according to [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)).

Comment: The first letter of my module name is the `L` in `Local::Λ`m which matches `/^[a-z_]/i`. As my example shows, Unicode module names *work* for real, and I don't care for cross-platform (→ personal use).

Comment: Yeh, I understand the personal use thing.  I just mention it to point out that you shouldn't expect much support for it in the existing code.  You can easily be looking into relatively new territory here.

Comment: Also the definition of 'word character' changes with: a) your version of perl.  b) If the script in question is using your input as a binary string or a character string.  Check out the 'a' & 'u' flags of recent versions of perl's regex engine.

Comment: The last part with the flag was a good hint, actually (although I don't have them, as I am pre-5.14). The documentation included examples on how to force unicode semantics, this did the trick: `perl -Mutf8 -M5.012 -MModule::Starter::App -E'$ARGV[1]="Local::\x{039B}";Module::Starter::App->run' -- --module Local::Λ --license gpl3 --ignore git` (Using `\x{...}` escapes forces unicode). Very hackish, but thank you.

Comment: You might want to refactor your answer to include the information that actually helped with the problem. I would then be honoured to accept it.